# Difference between List.add and manually adding item to a Riverpod StateNotifier<List<String>>

Tags: flutter, dart, state, riverpod

I'd like to learn how to use [Riverpod](https://riverpod.dev/), so to this end I'm implementing a small app that shows a list of items and a button that adds a dummy item to the list when tapped.

## Problem context

Pressing the button in the following app works as expected (a dummy item is added, and the change is immediately reflected in the UI):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';



void main() => runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(home: HomePage());
}



final itemsProvider = StateNotifierProvider((ref) => ItemsList());

class ItemsList extends StateNotifier<List<String>> {
  ItemsList([List<String> items]) : super(items ?? []);

  void add(String item) => state = [...state, item];
}



class HomePage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    final items = watch(itemsProvider.state);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: items.map((e) => Text(e)).toList(),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => context.read(itemsProvider).add('Other item'),
        tooltip: 'Add item',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

## Problem

Inside the `add` method of the `ItemsList` class, I thought that changing the statement `state = [...state, item]` to `state.add(item)` would not make any difference. However, doing so makes the app not responsive to state changes anymore: tapping the button doesn't trigger a change to the UI, and I don't see any new item in the UI until I hot-reload my app.

So just to be clear: changing `void add(String item) => state = [...state, item];` to `void add(String item) => state.add(item);` breaks the link between app state and UI.

Why is manually adding an item with list destructuring different from using `List.add`? Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The state must change in a way that `oldValue == newValue` is false.  And by default, adding elements to a list with `.add` mutates the list in place, so equality is *preserved*.  That's why's all the examples have something like `state = [...state, foo]`, so that an entirely new list is in state, and that's not equal to the old list.

Comment: it's should be something like .refresh() in case there is a very big list will copy into next each time is not optimal for performance, hope in future this gets fixed

Comment: Nothing to fix.  It's working as designed.  And if you're using the new providers (and not the pre 2.0 providers), you can call `ref.notifyListeners()` even after your mutate method has mutated state in place, just like a ChangeNotifier would need.